# setWorkingDirectory only works for Qt Creator

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am creating an app to run a specific .bat file. This function should execute the .bat file within the same directory as .exe file.

The following code works inside QtCreator, but not outside (when running exe file, it complains about non-existence of .BAT file).

How can I fix this?

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess( this );
process->setWorkingDirectory(qApp->applicationDirPath());
process->execute(qApp->applicationDirPath()+"\\getlist.bat");
qDebug() << "App path : " << qApp->applicationDirPath();
```

Comment: what is the output of `qDebug() << "App path : " << qApp->applicationDirPath();`? also how do you start your application?

Comment: On Qt Creator, I just use Run, otherwise I double click on EXE file in "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Pr\build-Pr-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug" which is also output of `qDebug. The BAT file also exists in that folder as well.

Comment: so your **getlist.bat** is in both folders?

Comment: no. both exe and bat files are in "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Pr\build-Pr-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug" dir.

Comment: did you tried it run in command line?

Comment: yes it is the same problem.

Comment: please post the current error message.

Comment: It says something like "Batch or command file not found"

Comment: something like? please copy the message

Comment: Sorry, it was Turkish, and I tried to translate into English. Here is the best match that I could found "The name specified is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. "